# Magmi Keeps Asking for Login

Tags: magento-1.9, login, redirect, magmi

I use **Magmi** with **Magento 1.9** for a few years now. All of a sudden, no matter what I do, press **“run”** or **“save profile”**, Magmi sends me to the **login page**.
Help anyone?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. In your VirtualHost configuration, find this line:

   ```
   ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/usr/home/jcc/www/$1
   ```
2. Add the following code right before the line mentioned above:

   ```
   SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
   ```

It should fix your issue.

Comment: My website is at managed VPS, I've been told it's not possible to make VirtualHost configuration in it. Any other solution?